# Get JSON Data as String in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin

I am using the following code which has no errors but I still get an expection error and not sure why:

```
fun getJsonDataFromAsset(context: Context, fileName: String): String? {
  val jsonString: String
  try {
    jsonString = context.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
  } catch (ioException: IOException) {
    ioException.printStackTrace()
    return null
  }
  return jsonString
}
```

Comment: what's the exception ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson and AssetsManager for extracting json from asset-file. For example:

```
private fun createGson() = GsonBuilder().create()

fun getJsonStringFromAssets(fileName: String, context:Context): String {
    val gson = createGson()
    return gson.fromJson<Response>(getAssetsFileAsString(fileName, context), object : TypeToken<Response>() {}.type)
}

private fun getAssetsFileAsString(path: String, context:Context): String? {
    return context.assets?.fileAsString(path)
}

private fun AssetManager.fileAsString(filename: String): String {
    return open(filename).use {
        it.readBytes().toString(Charset.defaultCharset())
    }
}
```

Where 'Response' is your json data class.